# Sort Array based on Time and Group

Tags: javascript, sorting, google-apps-script

lets say I have an array that looks like this

```
[ [AAAA, 2016-01-01, 1:00 PM, FA1], 
  [AAAA, 2016-01-01, 12:30 AM, FA1], 
  [BBBB, 2016-01-02, 6:00 PM, FA1], 
  [BBBB, 2016-01-02, 5:00 PM, FA1], 
  [CCCC, 2016-01-03, 9:00 PM, FA1], 
  [CCCC, 2016-01-03, 7:00 PM, FA1] ]
```

How to sort data that it will be look like this.

```
[ [AAAA, 2016-01-01, 12:30 AM, FA1], 
  [AAAA, 2016-01-01, 1:30 PM, FA1], 
  [BBBB, 2016-01-02, 5:00 PM, FA1], 
  [BBBB, 2016-01-02, 6:00 PM, FA1], 
  [CCCC, 2016-01-03, 7:00 PM, FA1], 
  [CCCC, 2016-01-03, 9:00 PM, FA1] ]
```

for now this is my code how ever it doesn't sort by time

```js
var inputarr = [
  ["AAAA", "2016-01-01, 1:00 PM", "FA1"],
  ["AAAA", "2016-01-01, 12:30 AM", "FA1"],
  ["BBBB", "2016-01-02, 6:00 PM", "FA1"],
  ["BBBB", "2016-01-02, 5:00 PM", "FA1"],
  ["CCCC", "2016-01-03, 9:00 PM", "FA1"],
  ["CCCC", "2016-01-03, 7:00 PM", "FA1"]
]



map = {};
for (var element in inputarr) {
  if (!map[inputarr[element][1]]) {
    map[inputarr[element][1]] = [];
  }
  map[inputarr[element][1]].push(inputarr[element]);
}
output = [];

for (var key in map) {
  output.push(map[key].shift());
  output.push(map[key].pop());
}
console.log(output);
```

Comment: I made a snippet and added quotes around the strings

Comment: You need to parse the time OR add a space to the hours < 10 - then you can object sort the date string

Answer (score 3):

you can sort date by using the `Date` object, and string using string method `localCompare`.

```js
x = [
  ['AAAA', '2016-01-01', '1:00 PM', 'FA1'], 
  ['AAAA', '2016-01-01', '12:30 AM', 'FA1'], 
  ['BBBB', '2016-01-02', '6:00 PM', 'FA1'], 
  ['BBBB', '2016-01-02', '5:00 PM', 'FA1'], 
  ['CCCC', '2016-01-03', '9:00 PM', 'FA1'], 
  ['CCCC', '2016-01-03', '7:00 PM', 'FA1']
]

x.sort((a, b) => {
  let aDate = new Date(`${a[1]} ${a[2]}`),
      bDate = new Date(`${b[1]} ${b[2]}`);

  if (+aDate == +bDate) {
    return a[0].localeCompare(b[0])
  }

  return aDate - bDate;
})

console.log(x)
```

Comment: next time. if you have a choice of using an object instead of an array, please do it. define a key label like, date, time, etc... its easier to understand and sort the data